# No WebFrame methods are recognized by compiler

Tags: cocoa, xcode4

This is a Cocoa app I am working on. I'm trying to embed a simple WebView with some basic content in an NSWindow in my app. I've wired my WebView to my NSWindowController, and anytime I try to pass a selector to that WebView, things are fine. But to load content, I need to use the WebFrame. And XCode refuses to recognize *any* methods in WebFrame (although it seems to recognize that WebFrame is a proper class.) For example:

```
[[webView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

generates a *'loadHTMLString: baseURL:' not found* compiler warning. It does function at runtime, but of course I'd like to eliminate the compiler warning.

Any thoughts on what's up?

Thanks in advance.

(Edited to add more code)

Below is from my ViewController's header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <WebKit/WebView.h>

@interface ReportViewController : NSWindowController {

   IBOutlet WebView *webView;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) WebView *webView;
```

And below here is a snippit from my Document implementation:

```
ReportViewController *window = [[ReportViewController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Report"];
[window showWindow:nil];
WebView *webView = [window webView];
[htmlData writeToFile:tmpfile atomically:YES];
```

Comment: How have you declared `webView`? Have you imported <WebKit/WebKit.h> in the implementation file?

Comment: Hi Bavarious, I declare the WebView in my WindowController (I added that code above). Indeed I import <WebKit/WebKit.h> in the WindowController header, but not the implementation. The class where my problem occurs is in my Document subclass; I pasted some of that code above as well. That class' header and impl both import <WebKit/WebView.h>

Comment: As soon as I posted my reply above, I saw the problem. I need to import <WebKit/WebKit.h> and not <WebKit/WebView.h>. Thanks Bavarious!

Comment: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Bavarious' hint, I realized that I needed to import <WebKit/WebKit.h> as opposed to <WebKit/WebView.h>.